# How to find the package name of an activity that appears between application

Tags: android

I am making an application that hides the number we are calling, but while we hung up the call a screen appears which shows the mobile number  How do I find the package name of that screen?

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
             //get a list of installed apps.
             List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

             for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
                 Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
             }
```

i tried this one,but am getting only my application package name not the `android's activity package name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably get the task that is running foreground and extract the package name from it.

```
 private String getCurrentTopPackage() {

        ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
        return ar.topActivity.getPackageName().toString();
    }
```

You should run a thread or timer task periodically to get the top most activities package name.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can get it by using:

Global to the class:

```
public static String PACKAGE_NAME;
```

In onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
}
```

You can then access it via Main.PACKAGE_NAME.